# How to programatically resize a QMainWindow to its minimum size

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, resize, qlayout

When I have a QMainWindow with a grid layout, when resizing it with the mouse, it won't go below some minimum size that's necessary for all the controls in it to show properly. In my app I sometimes programatically hide controls, but then the window remains the same size and the rest of the controls look spread out, with too much space between them. I end up resizing the dialog manually so it doesn't look ugly.

Can I programatically set the dialog's vertical size to this minimum I get when manually resizing after I've hidden controls in it?

Comment: +1 I'm frustrated by this too.

Comment: Just figured it out, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do the trick (it resizes only the height):

```
    QWidget widget;
    widget.resize(widget.width(), widget.minimumHeight());
```

Comment: How does this differ from `widget.resize(widget.width(), 1)?` And is there any difference between 0 and 1? (I'm a newbie, as you can obviously tell.)

Comment: Do you mean that widget.minimumHeight() returns 0? I had assumed that it returns the minimum size needed for all the controls to fit, but I haven't checked the actual value returned by the function.

Comment: This was helpful, in that, when using dock widgets, one can get the height of a top/bottom dock widget and then set the MainWindow's minimum size to it's current height minus the height of the dock widget you wish to hide.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that resizing the `centralWidget` in the `QMainWindow` then resizing the `QMainWindow` itself does the trick. In other words:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # define some widgets and stuff
    def whenWidgetsAreHidden(self):
        # this method should be triggered when you hide your widgets
        self.centralWidget.adjustSize()
        self.adjustSize()
```

Note that there are other widgets in the QMainWindowLayout. Per this image from the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html), there are also Dock Widgets and other stuff that could be present. I only use the `centralWidget` so this solution works for me.

[image: QMainWindow Layout]

Answer (score 1):

There is hierarchy between [QLayout::SizeConstraint](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#SizeConstraint-enum), [QWidget::minimumSizeHint](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop), [QWidget::minimumSize](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop), and you can find it in the documentation.

- `QWidget::minimumSize` is not set by default. When it is, it prevails over 
  `QWidget::minimumSizeHint`
- `QWidget::minimumSizeHint` is invalid if the widget is not in a layout (meaning that it can be resized to 0 with the mouse), otherwise use the one defined by the layout.
- `QLayout::SizeConstraint` holds the default layout behavior of the widgets it *directly * manage. If you nest a layout `A` within a layout `B`, all widgets added to `A` will use its property. Also if a widget `W` in `B` define its own layout, then this layout constraints are the one to be applied for the widget `W`.

Knowing that, follow these steps. It *might* work, i didn't try :) :

- Set the minimum size of all widgets you use.
- Ensure that the size constraint of all your layouts is set to `QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint`.